# Fancybox de prestashop no muestra las imágenes bien

Tags: jquery, prestashop

En la tienda de prestashop que estoy haciendo, el fancybox de los productos, el que muestra la imagen del producto en la caja del fancybox, no concuerdan las dimensiones de la caja con el tamaño de la miniatura o imagen.

Un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé porque deja tanto espacio en blanco. He probado a poner `FittoView:1!` en jquery.fancybox.js y he añadido `autoScale` y `AutoDimensions` en la función del fancybox pero esto último me he dado cuenta de que lo trae por defecto.

Éste es el último código que he intentado:

```
$('li:visible .fancybox, .fancybox.shown').fancybox({ 
    'hideOnContentClick': true, 
    'openEffect': 'elastic',
    'closeEffect': 'elastic', 
    'autoScale': true, 
    'autoDimensions': false, 
    'overlayShow':false, 
    'type':'image' 
});
```

Comment: añade tu código  con los parámetros que le pasas al fancybox

Comment: $('li:visible .fancybox, .fancybox.shown').fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
    'openEffect' : 'elastic',
    'closeEffect' : 'elastic',
    'autoScale': true,
    'autoDimensions': false,
    'overlayShow':false,
    'type':'image'
   }); Esto es lo último que he probado

Comment: edita [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/43820/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias dimensiones para las imagenes de los productos en Prestashop. Has probado a enlazar el fancybox con imagenes de mas resolucion y tamaño como `thickbox_default` o solamente la imagen original??

Suerte